# Escaping $ with \$ to avoid MathJax doesn't render properly on iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, markdown-rendering, mathjax

Following the [enabling of MathJax on 3D Printing Stack Exchange](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/314/4808) I've edited [this post](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/4015/4808) by replacing the `$$` with `\$\$`, so that the system doesn't think the user intended to start a MathJax block.

This looks fine on the desktop (not shown) and the mobile site (left). However, the iOS app (right) interprets the `\` literally.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Hmmm ... further investigation shows it could be a [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) issue. It's not working *at all* for 3D Printing, not even where it's intended to be used.

Comment: maybe 3D Printing can print escaped money?